Firebase API keys being exposed inside resouces.arsc -> strings.xml when the APK was analysed
The Google Firebase API keys can be seen when the APK is analysed in Android Studio and strings.xml inside the resources.arsc is opened, for a flutter app I'm developing.
Right now I'm using Envied for encrypting the API keys inside this app. But even after using it, the issue persists.
Since API keys being exposed is a serious issue. I hope there'll be some way to deal with this.

You can use Firebase remote config. And get api key at a run time.

But firebase remote config would also need the firebase key to work right? How can I keep the firebase key itself in remote config.
